# Is this stored procedure vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection, sql-server

My question is about what exploits are possible given the following, not how to prevent SQL injection. I would **not** use this code in a real application.

Using MSSQL Server 2019, imagine a stored procedure for a search that does something like:

```
DECLARE @keyword varchar(30); -- are there keyword values can cause injection?
SET @keyword = REPLACE(@keyword,  ​'''', '^');
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE REPLACE(Name, '''''', ''^'') LIKE CONCAT(''%'', ''' + @keyword + ''', ''%'')';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Which creates a dynamic sql query by replacing all `'` with `^`, in the keyword, as well as the column fields.

I don't know if SQL smuggling is viable because the `REPLACE` function will take out ascii and unicode apostrophes.

What attacks, if any, are possible?

P.S. I know using parameterized queries is the only sensible way of preventing sql injection attacks. I'm just curious to see if what techniques can be used to beat this sanitization approach in mssql.

Comment: The query uses the blacklist approach which is not recommended for security. Instead use a whitelist approach: check the input parameter if it only contains allowed characters and otherwise reject the query.

Comment: Thank you. My question is more about what inputs, if any, could cause sql injection.